# Upgrade permission denied: how to upgrade pip on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm new to Mac OS X. I want to set up an environment for python programming. 
I'm using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to manage the third party packages.

I installed pip with easy_install.

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

I tried to **upgrade pip from 6.1.0 to 6.1.1**. However, my request was declined and I got the following message.

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 6.1.0, however version 6.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 6.1.0
Uninstalling pip-6.1.0:
  Successfully uninstalled pip-6.1.0
Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
  root=options.root_path,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 711, in install
  **kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 806, in install
  self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1007, in move_wheel_files
  isolated=self.isolated,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 347, in move_wheel_files
  generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 323, in make
  self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 227, in _make_script
  self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 201, in _write_script
  self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 388, in write_binary_file
  with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
```

It seems I don't have the permission to upgrade pip. I think this isn't a problem of lack of dependent packages. The OS X system I'm using is OS X 10.10.3. And I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Run it wth `sudo`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You installed it with `sudo easy_install pip`, which makes the `pip` created by root user.

When upgrading it, you should also use:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```